# Draw colored circle around PNG

Tags: android

I am using this PNG in my project (within my resources):

[image]

Programmically, I want to achieve this:

1. Change color to white.
2. Add a solid-colored circle around the icon.

The result should look to something like this:

[image]

**The red color has to be changeable dynamically at runtime.** How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your XML file:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bull_image"
    app:tint="@android:color/white" />
```

This is `circle.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</shape>
```

And to change the background color dynamically:

```
imageView.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.your_color))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this shoud do the trick (adjust the cardCornerRadius to your liking):

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/red"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">
    
        <ImageView
            android:src="your_image"
            android:tint="@color/white" /> 
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a drawable that you can use as your background, for example:

   ```
   <!--  res/drawable/the_drawable_above.xml -->
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval" android:padding="10dp">
       <stroke android:width="1dp"
           android:color="@color/colorLightGrey"/>
       <solid
          android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
   </shape>
   ```
2. For your image view:

> ```
> <ImageView
>        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_image"
>         scale_type="fit_center"
>         android:tint="@android:color/white"
>         android:background="@drawable/the_drawable_above"/>
> ```